# How to do this in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, domaincontext

i having problem in converting this C# code into VB.net.
The loadLecturer seem to be having problem after convert to VB.NET

VB code just afterInitializeComponent()

```
context.Load(context.GetLecturesQuery(), LoadLecturer, Nothing)
```

The C# code i wish to convert and debug

```
private void LoadLecturer(LoadOperation<tblLecturer> obj)
{
    foreach (var item in obj.Entities)
    {
        cbLID.Items.Add(item.lecturerID + " - " + item.lfirstName + " " + item.llastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: And which aspect of that are you having problems with?

Comment: Error 1 Argument not specified for parameter 'obj' of 'Private Sub LoadLecturer(obj As System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation(Of Web.Lecture))'. C:\Users\Carson\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LotusUniversity\LotusUniversity\Views\Home.xaml.vb 13 50 LotusUniversity

Comment: From this line context.Load(context.GetLecturesQuery(), LoadLecturer, Nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the comment, it sounds like it's not the method itself which is causing you grief, but how you *call* it - because in the original code you're using a method group conversion. I suspect it's as simple as:

```
context.Load(context.GetLecturesQuery(), AddressOf LoadLecturer, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following this link [for the VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) this is what I am getting :)

```
Private Sub LoadLecturer(obj As LoadOperation(Of tblLecturer))
For Each item As var In obj.Entities
    cbLID.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(item.lecturerID) & " - " & Convert.ToString(item.lfirstName) & " " & Convert.ToString(item.llastName))
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I using this converter as well
But there is an error came from var. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub LoadLecturer(obj As LoadOperation(Of tblLecturer))
    For Each item As var In obj.Entities
        cbLID.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(item.lecturerID) & " - " & Convert.ToString(item.lfirstName) & " " & Convert.ToString(item.llastName))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I using this converter as well But there is an error came from var. Any idea ?